# SPARQL REPLACE back-reference syntax $ or backslash?

Tags: regex, sparql

According to the [SPARQL 1.1 W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex), regular expressions use the [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax), which defines backreferences with backslashes:

`[9a] backReference ::= "\" [1-9][0-9]*`

However using this syntax on the [DBpedia Virtuoso 07.20.3218 SPARQL Endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) results in an error:

`select replace(str(?class),"A.","\0\0") {  ?class a owl:Class. }`

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad escape sequence in a short double-quoted string at '"\'
```

However using `$` works:

`select replace(str(?class),"A.","$0$0") {  ?class a owl:Class. }`

Is this an oversight in the recommendation, a non-standard syntax in Virtuoso endpoints or did I misunderstand the recommendation?

Comment: It seems to me that you confuse inline backreferences with replacement backreferences here.

Comment: If I double escape then I just get the number itself as output, e.g. "\\0" returns "0".

Comment: Yeah, sure, that comment was incorrect. I have deleted it. The replacement backreference syntax is `$` + the ID of the capturing group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You confused the pattern inline backreferences that match the same text as already captured by a capturing group and a *replacement backreference* whose style is `$`+`digit(s)`. See the [`replace` reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace):

> Within the `$replacement` string, a ***variable $`N`*** may be used to refer to the substring captured by the Nth parenthesized sub-expression in the regular expression. For each match of the pattern, these variables are assigned the value of the content matched by the relevant sub-expression, and the modified replacement string is then substituted for the characters in `$input` that matched the pattern. `$0` refers to the substring captured by the regular expression as a whole.

Now, just [an example](https://regex101.com/r/WFvNYC/1): to duplicate the `A(.)B\1` pattern, you may replace it with `$0$0`, and `AnBn` will turn into `AnBnAnBn`. It will happen because `n` is captured with `(.)` and placed into Group 1 buffer, and `\1` inline backreference matches it further on. `$0` is a replacement backreference to the whole match, used in the replacement pattern, replacement argument to `replace` function.

Comment: Thanks! I confused the two because I didn't even know that pattern inline back-references exist.